# What does negative delta S imply?

Tags: entropy

What does it mean when there is a negative delta $S$ $(-\Delta S)$? One person asked if this implied negative entropy, but I don't see how this could be possible.

Does this imply a negative change in entropy? If the former, how can negative entropy exist?

Comment: entropy is just S.

Comment: Freezing or condensing water is a good example of a process where $\Delta S < 0$.

Comment: Delta means change, so negative delta mean decreasing of a value. An sure, yes, there are plenty of processes like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative delta S ($\Delta S <0$) is a decrease in entropy in regard to the system.

For **physical processes** the entropy of the universe still goes up but within the confines of the system being studied entropy decreases.

One example is a freezer with a cup of liquid water in it.  The freezer will utilize the electrical energy coming in to pump heat from the water until it becomes a solid (ice). At which point the entropy of the system (the contents of the freezer) decreases, however the electrical energy needed to be produced to power the freezer such as coal (burning a solid to a gas) and heat was wasted by the freezer in the process both of which create larger amounts of entropy than was reduced in the system by the freezer.

For **chemical processes** entropy can be a great driver of many reactions but it is not absolute. A system's favorability to release energy (enthalpy) competes with entropy. For example, an electron of hydrogen may have higher entropy if it drifts from the core proton but the electrostatic forces (and quantum mechanics) energetically keep it bound to the atom.  For isobaric processes, you much determine the change in Gibbs free energy for the reaction to know which way it is driven. For isochoric processes, you must determine the Helmholtz free energy to know which way a reaction is driven.

One example is the oxidation of iron in air.  When the oxygen is in the gas state it has higher entropy but the energy of bonding with iron is so great that at normal pressures oxygen goes from the gas phase and the iron rusts ("enthalpy wins") as delta G is negative.

Now we must consider statistical thermodynamics, this process is pressure dependent. At normal atmospheric pressure, the forward rate of oxygen entering the gas phase is the same as the reverse process. If the iron oxide were held in a sufficiently high vacuum the reverse process would occur and the iron oxide would reduce back to iron like many asteroids ("entropy wins"; note: thermodynamics is equilibrium after an infinite time). Accounting for pressure modifies the Gibbs free energy equation to: $$\Delta G = \Delta G^\circ -RT \ln(P) = \Delta H^\circ -T\Delta S^\circ -RT \ln(P)$$

One thing to note is that for chemical reactions the entropy and enthalpy values are for a standard temperature (such as $298\ \text{K}$). For a spontaneous system with $\Delta S^\circ < 0$ enthalpy must be negative, this heat in reality is absorbed by the system or the environment and produces entropy according to:  $$ \int \mathrm dS \equiv \int \frac{C_v}{T}\,\mathrm dT \equiv \int \frac{\mathrm dQ}{T} $$

This in and of itself produces some entropy in the universe though may not net above zero as the bonding energy is still the major driving force.

Comment: Hmm, but $-\Delta S$ does not mean negative $S$ change, but negatively taken $\Delta S$. Similarly, $-T$ does not mean negative absolute temperature $T$, but negatively taken (as for subtraction) positive $T$.

Answer (score 1):

If a quantity $q$ is smaller than zero, we say that it is negative. Mathematically, we would write: $$q < 0$$

When we write $-q$, it instructs us to change the sign of $q$. If $q$ is positive, $-q$ is negative. If $q$ is negative, $-q$ is positive. If you see $-\Delta S$ in a mathematical expression, it does not mean $\Delta S$ is negative. It could be either positive or negative, and putting a negative sign in front of it changes it to the opposite.

The value of $\Delta S$ is defined as a difference between two entropies $S_1$ and $S_2$. You expect entropies $S_1$ and $S_2$ both to be positive, but the difference is either positive or negative, depending which of $S_1$ and $S_2$ is larger.

You have the same situation for temperature expressed using the Kelvin scale. All temperatures are positive, but a temperature change can either be an increase in temperature ($\Delta T$ is positive) or a decrease in temperature ($\Delta T$ is negative).